# Time Limit Exceeded for Binary Search in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, search, binary-search

I have created a binary search program in python but I am getting "time limit exceeded" for one of the test cases. Any idea how I can optimize my code to reduce the running time?

My code basically finds the index of the median term and compares the query to the integer at the median. I then update the array to either the left half (if the query is less than the median) or the right half (if the query is more than the median).

If the query is equal to the median, then the index is returned.

If the length of the array is 1 and the query is not equal to the sole integer in the array, -1 is returned. Otherwise the index of the sole integer in the array is returned.

Below is my code.

Thanks everyone for your help!

```
def binary_search(keys, query):
    array_to_search = keys
    
    while len(array_to_search) > 1:
        median = len(array_to_search) // 2
        if q < array_to_search[median]:
            # split list from starting point up to median index
            array_to_search = array_to_search[:median]
            continue
        elif q > array_to_search[median]:
            # split list from median index up to last index
            array_to_search = array_to_search[median:]
            continue
        else:
            return keys.index(array_to_search[median])
    
    if q == array_to_search[0]:
        return keys.index(array_to_search[0])
    else:
        return -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_keys = int(input())
    input_keys = list(map(int, input().split()))
    assert len(input_keys) == num_keys

    num_queries = int(input())
    input_queries = list(map(int, input().split()))
    assert len(input_queries) == num_queries

    for q in input_queries:
        print(binary_search(input_keys, q), end=' ')
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what the code is supposed to do. We can guess a little from what you say about your code, but please quote the code challenge literally in your question.

Comment: There is no benefit from a binary search if in the end you are calling `.index()`, which is just doing a linear search. You might as well then skip the whole binary search and immediately do `keys.index(q)`.

Comment: If your recursion includes the median then there's a possibility of an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh, and using `keys.index` will do a linear search, negating the whole point of a binary search.

Comment: Can you share the inputs and outputs that have you tried for testing? @YongKheeHou

Comment: Ah thanks for the insight about .index()!

Comment: The challenge is as follows. In this problem, you will implement the binary search algorithm that allows searching very efficiently (even huge) lists, provided that the list is sorted. The goal in this code problem is to implement the binary search algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm was in an infinite loop, hence the "time limit exceeded" error.

With the caveat that there are definitely more efficient ways to implement binary search, I think your logic can be adjusted to make a working version as follows:

```py
#def binary_search(keys, query): # used different argument name 'query' from the name 'q' used in the function body
def binary_search(keys, q):
    array_to_search = keys
    
    i = 0 # we need to track changes to the start of the array
    while len(array_to_search) > 1:
        median = len(array_to_search) // 2
        if q < array_to_search[median]:
            # split list from starting point up to median index
            array_to_search = array_to_search[:median]
            continue
        elif q > array_to_search[median]:
            # split list from median index up to last index
            #array_to_search = array_to_search[median:] # median has already been checked, so we can start at median + 1 instead
            array_to_search = array_to_search[median + 1:]
            i += median + 1 # we need to track changes to the start of the array
            continue
        else:
            return i + median # return value needs to reflect changes to the start of the array
    
    #if q == array_to_search[0]: # we need to check that the array is not empty
    if array_to_search and q == array_to_search[0]:
        return i # return value needs to reflect changes to the start of the array
    else:
        return -1

def foo():
    '''
    #I have eliminated the input logic for testing purposes
    num_keys = int(input())
    input_keys = list(map(int, input().split()))
    assert len(input_keys) == num_keys

    num_queries = int(input())
    input_queries = list(map(int, input().split()))
    assert len(input_queries) == num_queries
    '''

    # here is an arbitrary test case
    input_keys = [0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
    input_queries = [0,6,12,18,20,-1,9,21]

    for q in input_queries:
        print(binary_search(input_keys, q), end=' ')

foo()
```

Output:

```
0 3 6 9 10 -1 -1 -1
```

Regarding efficiency improvements, note that slicing operations such as `array_to_search[:median]` and `array_to_search[median + 1:]` will make copies which will take something like n/2 time for the first one, then n/4 for the second, then n/8 etc, adding O(n) time complexity to binary search, an algorithm that could otherwise be O(log n). This is why it is often implemented instead using two pointers (such as `left` and `right`) to track the ever-shrinking subarray within which the search is being conducted. You may want to take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure) for an example of this.

Comment: I see! Thanks for your help. The running time for the algorithm improved significantly but it still exceeds the time limit. I think the improvement is largely due to the elimination of the use of .index(). But as you suggested, the algorithm is probably still exceeding the time limit due to the additional time it takes to create the new arrays.

Comment: I'll use your tip to use the 2 pointers to implement the algorithm. Thanks for your help! Learnt a lot about how to troubleshoot the running time of my algo and to improve its efficiency!

Comment: Glad to hear this was helpful to you. Let me know if you need any more help, and please feel free to mark this answer as "accepted".

Comment: Also, could I clarify why my algo was in an infinite loop as you suggested at the start of your reply? Thanks

Comment: As @Mark Ransom pointed out, your line reading `array_to_search = array_to_search[median:]` is including the median in the next search range when you've already determined that it can be excluded, and this can lead to an infinite loop. You will notice that I changed it to `array_to_search = array_to_search[median + 1:]` which is the standard logic for binary search (though typically using pointers, not slices).

Comment: Congratulations for pointing out that making list slices will be a major time waster too.  Note that passing a whole list to a function without slicing is very quick by comparison.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRansom too! Also, could I clarify what you are referring to when you said 'by passing a whole list to a function', Mark?

Comment: @Young42 for example if you wanted to make a recursive function, you could define it as `def binary_search(keys, query, left=0, right=None)` and if you then call it with `return binary_search(keys, query, left, median-1)` you would not make a copy of `keys` and the call would be fast.